# Loop using For i=... incredibly slows down and stop for large values of i or for large data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to match two sets of data by comparing their dates.

If the data matches, both set of data are then copied, otherwise, the next date on the second set of data is searched for to match the date on the first set of data (first set of data as less amount of numbers stored than the second set of data).

For small values of `i` it works fine; for large values of `i` is very slow; if the whole range of i is used (i.e. 3 to 51490) it stops.

I believe it must be something related to the `For`, to the loop and to the fact that I'm writing to cells instead of array, but I don't know how to change my code.

Here it is (by the way, all the application changes improved absolutely nothing):

```
Sub Merge_data()
Dim i, m, j As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

CalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Application.Cursor = xlWait

For i = 51003 To 51103 ' 3 To 51490 until the cell where the date is equal to: 12/30/2016  11:50:00 PM, i.e. row 51490

    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 5).Value Then
        For m = 1 To 3 '
            Cells(i, m + 8).Value = Cells(i, m).Value
            Cells(i, m + 12).Value = Cells(i, m + 4).Value
        Next m
    Else
        j = i + 1
        Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(j, 5).Value
            If j = 52562 Then ' The value 52562 corresponds to the last row where there is data available
                Exit Do
            End If
            For m = 1 To 3 ' 11
                Cells(i, m + 8).Value = Cells(i, m).Value
                Cells(i, m + 12).Value = Cells(j + 1, m + 4).Value
            Next m
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    End If
Next i
EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.Cursor = xlNormal
End Sub
```

Comment: "the fact that I'm writing to cells instead of array" is correct. Check the "Read/Write Large Blocks of Cells in a Single Operation" section in https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

Comment: Please edit your question so it is not a big block of text. It is off-putting to read without some spacing.

Comment: You forgot to turn ScreenUpdating back on. Related to performance, using arrays will solve half of the problem, but you also hava 3 levels of nesting in loops - each level increases processing time exponentially. If you can’t explain the end goal in a simpler way it will be difficult to improve the second half

Comment: I'm not going to try and wrap my head around all the loops with data i can't see but there seems an immediate opportunity to lose each of the loops using m = 1 to 3 and simply use a range size e.g.   Cells(i, 9).Resize(, 3).Value2 = Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 3).Value2  and 
        Cells(i, 13).Resize(, 3).Value2 = Cells(i, 5).Resize(, 3).Value2 and later   in Do Loop 
                Cells(i, 9).Resize(, 3).Value2 = Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 3).Value2 and 
                Cells(i, 13).Resize(, 3).Value2 = Cells(j + 1, 5).Resize(, 3).Value2

Comment: You aren't resetting event handling at the end of the sub (maybe you need to swap that line around?)

Comment: If there are no matches it appears to perform 2 billion comparisons - a bit slow seems reasonable. Can you not sort the dates and then stop comparing if you go past the searched for date? This will shortcut the searching considerably

Answer (score 0):

This is your code based on arrays.

```
Sub Merge_data()
    Dim i As Long, m As Long, j As Long
    Dim vR() As Variant, vR2() As Variant, vDB As Variant
    Dim r As Long

    r = 511103 - 51003 + 1

    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 3): ReDim vR2(1 To r, 1 To 3)
    vDB = Range("a" & 51003).Resize(r, 8)

    For i = 1 To r ' 3 To 51490 until the cell where the date is equal to: 12/30/2016  11:50:00 PM, i.e. row 51490

        If vDB(i, 1) = vDB(i, 5) Then
            For m = 1 To 3 '
                vR(i, m) = vDB(i, m)
                vR2(i, m) = vDB(i, m + 4)
            Next m
        Else
            For j = 1 To r
                If vDB(i, 1) = vDB(j, 5) Then
                    For m = 1 To 3 ' 11
                        vR(i, m) = vDB(j, m)
                        vR2(i, m) = vDB(j + 1, m + 4)
                    Next m
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    Range("i51003").Resize(r, 3) = vR
    Range("m51003").Resize(r, 3) = vR2
End Sub
```